Is vertex mass the mass of the whole object?
Is the vertex mass setting for cloth simulations the mass of each individual vertex or is it the weight of the whole object? Like if a plane has 100 vertices and the vertex mass is 2 then is the weight of the cloth 2kg or 200kg? Because blender documentation makes it seem like it’s the weight of the whole object not each vertex. So is the vertex mass the weight of the whole thing or just one vertex? And if a plane has 100 vertices and I want the weight of the whole mesh to be 10kg then do I set the number to 10kg or do I set it to 10kg/100 vertices?

Indeed the doc is not clear, but the tooltip (when hovering in Blender) says "The mass of each vertex on the cloth material". I'd say it's the mass per vertex.

Oh ok thank you so much :) I was confused cause the two things counteracting eachother. So if an object weighs 10kg do I set it to 10kg or 10kg divided by the amount of vertices?

10kg / vertex count, for sure

Oh ok, thank you so much :)

Also do you know if the “friction” and “bounciness” settings for rigid body sim use any real world units or metrics? Or just units or metrics in general?

I'm not sure, rule of thumb : if the unit isn't specified, then it's not a real world thing.

Well friction coefficients don't have units. They're just a multiplier. Physical coefficients act like "friction force = coefficient * normal_force". Also, bounciness can very well be a coefficient as well, meaning things like how much energy is conserved after the colusion.   1 being fully conserved and 0 totally wasted.

I think I found that friction is coefficient of friction and bounciness is coefficient of restitution. They both use a range of 0-1. Also some things that don’t specify there unit in blender do use them like viscosity uses kinetic viscosity

Easy to test.
Make a plane and transform it into a cloth. It has 4 vertices.
Add a wind and turn off gravity.
Then subdivide the plane and start again.
Check the acceleration.

Starting (frame zero)

[



After 50 frames (4 vertices)





After 50 frames subdivided (25 vertices - nothing else changed)


Conclusion:
It's "mass" per vertex.

Oh ok thank you :)

@Fution F Fusion if the answer is correct, mark it as such   ;)

Oh sorry, how do I do that? This is my first post here thats been answered

@FutionFFusion, there is a checkmark on the left side of each answer.

Ohhh ok thank you :)
